# HighCharts: Getting rid of tooltip but mantain crosshairs

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using HighCharts, and I would like to use the crosshairs from the tooltip to help the user to hover a particular point.  When the point is hovered I would like to show the information of that point in another div (that is done), but I would like to prevent the tooltip box to appears.  Here is the "working" code: http://jsfiddle.net/Mw8WB/266/ . As you can see, I did a display:none in the tooltip, but there is a "circle" that is still there.

Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the tooltip options is formatter. It is a callback function to format the text of the tooltip. You can disable the tooltip by returning false from this function.

You can see the example here

http://jsfiddle.net/76LwZ/

and the documentation here

http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#tooltip